# How to pronounce the double consonant found in a word other than "nn"?

Tags: pronunciation

ちょっと here have a double consonant "t" . In double consonant the small つ is read as a silent speech(which will be symbolized by "_" for this question). Is it... Cho_to or chot_to or both?

Comment: The double consonant is used to signify a glottal stop.  This sound is present in the English pronunciation of "chipotle". Notice how the "t" isn't actually being pronounced?  The word winds up sounding like "chipo-le" where the - is the sound you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちょっと is pronounced chot_to, the consonant after っ is always doubled and put on both sides of the silent speech.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVynW7frBig) is a good video which explains this really well I think and shows you the pronunciation as well.

I hope this helps